# Android Time Picker shows in portrait and is cut off in landscape

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am trying to get the time picker to display the full clock in landscape. The `TimePicker` is in a `GridLayout`. It does not overlay the screen as a `DialogFragment` or a `TimePickerDialog`.

Currently, this is what it shows in landscape:

[image: Only time from time picker shown]

As you can see, there is nothing you can pick the time with, only the default time. I am trying to get it to show the clock as well just like in portrait (which works):

[image: Full time picker shown]

The layout of the time picker:

```
<package.name.ScrollableTimePicker
                android:id="@+id/time_picker"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

The class that extends `TimePicker`:

```
public class ScrollableTimePicker extends TimePicker {

    public ScrollableTimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ScrollableTimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollableTimePicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Keeps events to time picker
        if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ViewParent p = getParent();
            if (p != null) {
                p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I looked around the internet and found these posts that *did not* help me:

1. [Android TimePicker not displayed well on landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494234/android-timepicker-not-displayed-well-on-landscape-mode)

I do not have a title for my time picker.

2. [ScrollView fighting with scroll of TimePicker, Timepicker not scrolling as a result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354006/scrollview-fighting-with-scroll-of-timepicker-timepicker-not-scrolling-as-a-res)

It has already been implemented

3. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201766

Tried the code in manifest but still did not work.

**UPDATE**
As siddesh has suggested, setting `layout_height` of the `TimePicker` to `200dp` works but it cuts off the portrait. Now, the portrait is `200dp` tall but is cut off and the landscape is shown fully:

[image: Landscape TimePicker with height 200dp fully shown]

[image: Portrait TimePicker with height 200dp, with half cut off.]

Comment: its better to dismiss datepickerdialog on orientation change Default calendar do same thing check you calendar app to set alarm clock

Comment: @siddhesh It is not a DatePickerDialog, it is a TimePicker (and not a TimePickerDialog either)

Comment: same thing dude please check when you set your alarm on your cell click timepicker and rotate your phone timer gets dismiss

Comment: @siddhesh So the TimePicker gets dismissed when I rotate my phone? But why does still work when I rotate back?

Comment: i didnt get it what you are trying to say its better to use dismiss on timepicker to dismiss

Comment: @siddhesh What do you want me to dismiss? The TimePicker is not in a Dialog or DialogFragment. It is part of a GridLayout. It does not overlay the activity.

Comment: but the view you are providing it looks like dialog frament

Comment: @siddhesh It is just a cropped picture from my GridLayout.

Comment: then do workaround set  android:layout_height="200dp" or any other it will work for scrolltimepicker

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too when the TimePicker was in a ScrollView, your diagnosis was helpful.

You could set the height of the TimePicker programmatically in your activity.

In onCreate() add:

```
TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.time_picker);

// get display dimensions
Point p = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);

int newHeight;

if(p.x > p.y) {
    // if landscape, convert 200dp to px
    newHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
} else {
    newHeight = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
}

// set TimePicker height
tp.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
```